# Selecionar uma lista de valores e dessa lista, selecionar o menor valor

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select, sql-select

Estou querendo selecionar as 10 últimas inserções de uma tabela e dentre esses 10, retornar o menor valor. É possível fazer isso em uma única consulta?

Selecionando os 10 últimos valores:

```
SELECT id_relevo FROM relevo 
ORDER BY id_relevo DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendo direto, é possível fazer isso por exemplo utilizando uma subquerie.

```
 SELECT min(id_relevo) FROM 
(SELECT id_relevo FROM relevo ORDER BY id_relevo DESC LIMIT 10) as minimo
```

Comment: É exatamente isso mesmo. Muito obrigada!